# Visual Studio 2013 for Web is not showing the updated result in browser after updating code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, browser, visual-studio-2013

I am using VS 2013 for web. When I update the html in cs.html it is not rendering the updated view in browser and keep showing me the old view that was before editing the html file. To see the updated view I have to clear the browsing data of the browser after every update I make in the html in cs.html file.
Having this issue for a couple of days have tried so many solutions, but nothing solved this issue. Never face these issues before.
Any suggestions how can I fix this issue.

Comment: Are you using cache? If so, try to disable it in your browser (Google Chrome Developer Tools has an option inside Network menu).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View does not refresh after change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085396/view-does-not-refresh-after-change)

Comment: @DouglasGandini i have tried this cache disabling option but the problem remain the same.

Comment: Check out the question/answer above. Maybe the second answer could help you.