# razor pages. Show changes in browser after refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am trying to develop the app with new razor pages technology. When I add any changes to cshtml I want to be able to see these changes on the page after refresh, but there is no changes until I completely rerun a website from visual studio. It's not related only to tag-helpers it's also simple html modifying. Is there any way to make it work properly?
ENV - VS2017, ASP.NET CORE 2.0

Comment: you could host it on `IIS`

Comment: That's odd.  I'm using VS2017, with razor page on IIS Express and with browser link turned on, so if I'm running the web project I need only save the razor file and the browser will refresh.  You may want to read up on browser link.

Answer (score 2):

Anecdotally, I've noticed that running under IIS or IIS Express often will not result in changes automatically taking effect for me. I'm not sure if that's a real issue or just something to do with my setup. In order to get changes to automatically apply, I need to run the application itself.

In Visual Studio, in the debug target dropdown in the toolbar (the button with the green "play" icon), choose the item that matches your project's name (instead of IIS Express). This pops a console window (which is helpful on it's own) and I've found that when I then make changes to the code, that console window will reload, basically restarting the app hosting to pick up the new changes.

Again, this is all anecdotal. There may be an actual way to get it to work without doing it this way. Honestly, I just haven't been bothered to fool with it since 1) it works this way for me and 2) I actually like having the console there to see the requests coming through.

Comment: had the same issue even on VS 2019, and this worked for me for some reason. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help!
I found the solution on 
[View does not refresh after change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085396/view-does-not-refresh-after-change). 
It was shared folder. Currently it works by default!