# ASPNET CORE 3 browsers never reload with F5

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

VS2019, ASPNET CORE 3.0, WIN10, EDGE / IE, Razor PageModel

When the page is loaded (in debug mode), I made some changes to the cshtml file, the press F5. The page refresh, but never fetch the latest version. the OnGet() function in the Model page did invoked.

I thought when pressing F5, the browser will always fetch the latest HTML regardless the cache settings?

This makes my debugging extremely difficult. May I know how can I disable the caching, at least in debug mode?

Comment: have you heard of caching? not necessarily, you might need to recompile. Try setting up browser link

Comment: You can use Ctrl + F5 (hard reload).

Comment: Some browsers overly aggressive caching (especially Firefox) and lack of clever invalidation is a pain in the ass

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.0#runtime-compilation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2022, ASP.NET website with Razor pages, in order to see the changes to plain HTML directly when refreshing browser, without rebuilding you project you need to:

1. Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation NuGet package.
2. In Program.cs, change "**builder.Services.AddRazorPages();**" to "**builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();**"

This seems borderline ridiculous on many levels ;-) but it works.

Answer (score 1):

To reload **cshtml** files on the browser when the source code has changed check your web.config, and inside `<system.web>` make sure you do not have `fcnMode="Disabled"` or `fcnMode="NotSet"`

use

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" fcnMode="Default" />
```

or

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" fcnMode="Single" />
```

**(Make sure you change the targetFramework version by yours)**

[Source here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085396/view-does-not-refresh-after-change)

If you want to completely **disable the Google Chrome cache (to reload .js files or .css files)**, the setting is hidden in the developer options. Here’s how to access it in the Windows, OS X, and Linux versions.

1. Select the “Menu” button in the upper-right corner, then select “More
   tools” > “Developer tools“. You can also get to this screen by
   pressing Ctrl + Shift + I for Windows and Linux or Command + Option +
   I for Mac OS X.
2. The Dev Tools window appears. Select “Network“,
3. Check the “Disable cache” box.

If this does not reload the non-cshtml files, you can also do it manually by opening the chrome dev tools, right-clicking on the chrome refresh page icon and then selecting **Clear cache and reload...**

Comment: This question is about ASPNET CORE 3. There is no `web.config` by default, in a standard, template-generated web app project.